# SQL Question, Using NOT EXIST in a Subquery to Create Group Identifier

Tags: sql

I was going over the Island Problem in a SQL workbook, but I cannot understand the first step. The query looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
    col1 INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO dbo.T1(col1)
    VALUES(2), (3), (11), (12), (13), (27), (33), (34), (35), (42)


SELECT col1,
    (SELECT MIN(B.col1)
     FROM dbo.T1 AS B
     WHERE B.col1 >= A.col1
        AND NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT * 
             FROM dbo.T1 AS C           
             WHERE C.col1 = B.col1 + 1)) AS grp
FROM dbo.T1 AS A
```

The ouput should like something like this:

```
Col1      grp
--------------
2           3
3           3
11        13   
12        13
13        13
...        ...
```

What is the NOT EXIST Subquery returning?  I would think it returns 3 for the for the record (C.col1 = B.col1 + 1) = 3 which means it exists in table C. Therefore, how is it returning 3?

I don't understand how the NOT EXIST Statement is able to find the last value of each group.  Please explain how this query works, and how I should be reading it to understand what is happening. Thank you!

Comment: They syntax of this query is not correct. The parentheses are off, and that is making it difficult to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for each value of `Col1` consider all the values that are equal or greater:

> 2: (2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 27, 33, 34, 35, 42)
>
> 3: (3, 11, 12, 13, 27, 33, 34, 35, 42)
>
> 11: (11, 12, 13, 27, 33, 34, 35, 42)
>
> 12: (12, 13, 27, 33, 34, 35, 42)
>
> 13: (13, 27, 33, 34, 35, 42)
>
> 27: (27, 33, 34, 35, 42)
>
> 33: (33, 34, 35, 42)
>
> 34: (34, 35, 42)
>
> 35: (35, 42)
>
> 42: (42)

Now from each list:
remove all the values for which **there exists another value which is greater by 1** 

and return the minimum of the remaining values:

> 2:    (<del>2</del>,  **3**, <del>11</del>, <del>12</del>, 13, 27, <del>33</del>, <del>34</del>, 35, 42)
>
> 3:    (**3**, <del>11</del>, <del>12</del>, 13, 27, <del>33</del>, <del>34</del>, 35,
>   42)
>
> 11:   (<del>11</del>, <del>12</del>, **13**, 27, <del>33</del>, <del>34</del>, 35, 42)
>
> 12:   (<del>12</del>, **13**, 27, <del>33</del>, <del>34</del>, 35, 42)
>
> 13:   (**13**, 27, <del>33</del>, <del>34</del>, 35, 42)
>
> 27:   (**27**, <del>33</del>, <del>34</del>, 35, 42)
>
> 33:   (<del>33</del>, <del>34</del>, **35**, 42)
>
> 34:   (<del>34</del>, **35**, 42)
>
> 35:   (**35**, 42)
>
> 42:   (**42**)

Comment: Thank you!  this visualization is exactly what I needed to understand how the NOT EXISTS works.  I was removing the wrong values (the inverse of what you show here) and could not figure out why I kept getting 2 for 2.

Answer (score 1):

The query is grouping all sequential values into islands such that a gap forms on the last value of the sequence where no value +1 exists. The NOT EXISTS is a shortcut to marking the islands with a function such as LEAD and then using another query to rank order the groups.

The NOT EXIST is in a subquery of a derived field that is executed for each value in A. In essence, the query produces each value of A.col1 and whatever is returned from the subquery aliased as grp. The MIN(B) is what pulls only one value back for each of A, else you would get a subquery contains more than one value exception.

It is basically saying for each value in T1 that is greater than T1 in A as B take the MIN(B) when values in T1 as C is does not have an + 1 equivalent. THE NOT EXIST will always be false even for 100,000 sequential values because the last for the 99,999th value the NULL would cause the NOT EXIST to be true. However, the key is it not being false and the values being limited by B.col1 >= A.col1.

Caution --

The query above will not scale well. In fact at about 1,000 items the query below will start outperform the query you posted by a scale of 4:1 and then continue to outperform at a greater factor as the record count grows. If you are running SQL Server, output the statistics after filling a table with 1000 rows and then little by little add more rows to the test table. You will see a big difference in performance as the #records grow.

```
;WITH GroupMarkers AS
(
    SELECT col1,
        LastValueInGroup = CASE WHEN LEAD(col1) OVER( ORDER BY col1) = col1 + 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM dbo.T1
)
SELECT 
    T1.col1,MIN(GroupMarkers.col1) 
FROM 
    dbo.T1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupMarkers ON GroupMarkers.LastValueInGroup=1 AND GroupMarkers.col1 >= T1.col1 
GROUP BY
    T1.col1
```

Answer (score 1):

`not exists` is going to evaluate to true or false. The `select *` inside the subquery is just a throwaway result. All we care about is whether any rows are found.

The non-existence of a row with a value of one more than the one we're looking at means it is at the boundary of an island. Exactly what you want to find.

To paraphrase the entire query: Look at each value in the table in succession. Find all the boundary values greater or equal to that value using the logic above. Keep only the smallest one because it's the boundary of the current island (the smallest and closest one.) In that way all the values in an island will be associated with the same group.